# Is it secure to add headers with a request payload in a web service call

Tags: spring, spring-integration

[web service integration - how to access request Object in response class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702545/web-service-integration-how-to-access-request-object-in-response-class/55125474#55125474)

We are using http inbound gateway

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="RequestChannel" url="${test.url}" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" http-method="POST" reply-channel="ResponseChannel"></int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

I have a similar requirement i'm adding the request payload into the headers and making a webservice call.I have the sensitive information in my request and how secure it will be when i transmit the data over network.Is there any other approach i can follow to access the request object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is that this kind of headers is not transmitted over Web Service call by default.

If you don't map your custom header name in the:

```
<xsd:attribute name="mapped-request-headers" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
Comma-separated list of names of SOAP Headers to be mapped from the SOAP request into the MessageHeaders.
This can only be provided if the 'header-mapper' reference is not being set directly. The values in
this list can also be simple patterns to be matched against the header names (e.g. "foo*" or "*foo").
                        ]]></xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

it is not going to be included in the target SOAP request, neither HTTP headers.

So, it is fully secure to store your sensitive data in the headers before performing Web Service call and restore that data downstream after receiving reply.

Although you definitely need to think about removing that header some place after using anyway. Some other components may not restrict headers from transmitting.

**UPDATE**

In case of an `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` there is a `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` by default which is configured only to map some standard request-based HTTP headers. End-user custom headers are not mapped by default. Essentially the same way as I described for Web Services.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my post we are using the http outbound gateway.How do we handles this for REST calls.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.